# How to change the filed names of a JSON array?

Tags: php, mysql, json

in my database I have a table named "sensors", which has 3 fields: the NodeID field, the SensorID field and the Variable field. I want to select all sensors with a specific NodeID (e.g. 4) and present them in a JSON formatted array with SensorID - Variable pairs. Here is the code I use:

```
$query = "SELECT SensorID,Variable FROM sensors WHERE SensorID=4;
$result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die('query not made');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $sensors[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($sensors);
```

It works fine. However, the created array has the following format:

```
[
 { "SensorID": ..., "Variable": ... },
 { "SensorID": ..., "Variable": ... },
 ...
]
```

But I need it to have a different one:

```
[
 { "label": ..., "value": ... },
 { "label": ..., "value": ... },
 ...
]
```

In other words, I need to maintain the data of the first array, but change the field names.
So, how can I change the above PHP code to get that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to change your query:

`$query = "SELECT SensorID As label, Variable AS value FROM sensors WHERE SensorID=4;"`

Another option in case the above isn't suitable for whatever reason:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $sensors[] = array(
        'label' => $row['SensorId'],
        'value' => $row['Variable']
    );
}
```